# short if statement in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Can i make short that my code IF statement in one single IF Statement?

```
  If randomNumber = strWords2(StrwrVal.Text) Then
                    Else
                        If randomNumber = strWords3(StrwrVal.Text) Then
                        Else
                            If randomNumber = strWords4(StrwrVal.Text) Then
                            Else
                                If randomNumber = strWords5(StrwrVal.Text) Then
                                Else
                           TxtRnd1.Text = TxtRnd1.Text & vbNewLine & randomNumber
End if
End if
End if
End if
```

Comment: `If randomNumber <> strWords2(StrwrVal.Text) AndAlso randomNumber <> strWords3(StrwrVal.Text) AndAlso randomNumber <> strWords4(StrwrVal.Text) AndAlso randomNumber <> strWords5(StrwrVal.Text) Then ...`.

Comment: This, however, seems like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You probably could get a better answer if you explain what you're trying to achieve in the first place.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily recommend this because it's more code golf than maintainable code, but... `If Not {strWords2(StrwrVal.Text), strWords3(StrwrVal.Text), strWords4(StrwrVal.Text), strWords5(StrwrVal.Text)}.Contains(CStr(randomNumber)) Then TxtRnd1.Text = TxtRnd1.Text & vbNewLine & randomNumber` (I think this will also require importing `System.Linq` at the top of the file.)

Comment: Also, there may be some situations where using a `HashSet` works better, though I wouldn't necessarily recommend it for your case where even in the case where you run a loop with a lot of iterations, performance will be dominated by appending text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should NEVER have an empty `If` block.  If you don't want to do something if a condition is `True`, don't test whether that condition is `True` in the first place.  Test for the inverse condition.  In your case, you should be doing this:

```
If randomNumber <> strWords2(StrwrVal.Text) AndAlso
   randomNumber <> strWords3(StrwrVal.Text) AndAlso
   randomNumber <> strWords4(StrwrVal.Text) AndAlso
   randomNumber <> strWords5(StrwrVal.Text) Then
    TxtRnd1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & randomNumber)
End if
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a bunch of `Else` and `If`, or a bunch of `ElseIf`, you can use a `Select Case`. It's easier to read, among other things.

The `Select Case` will evaluate a variable and you can choose the outcome depending on what you find. You can also test for `True` if you want to evaluate things more complicated than one variable.

```
Select Case randomNumber
    Case strWords2(StrwrVal.Text)
        'some code
    Case strWords3(StrwrVal.Text)
        'some other code
    Case strWords4(StrwrVal.Text)
        'you got the idea
    Case Else
        TxtRnd1.Text = TxtRnd1.Text & vbNewLine & randomNumber
End Select
```

For what I read this would be the cleanest answer, but it always depends on the algorithm. Have fun!